# Derivative of $f(x)=-6\sin^4 x$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> $f(x)=-6\sin^4x$

$f(x)=-6\sin x^4$

$f'(x)=-6\cos x^4(4x^3)=-24x^3\cos x^4$

What am I doing wrong? Please show the steps.

Comment: Lower by one the power of cosine...and put $\;\sin^3x\;$ instead of that weird $\;x^3\;$, which has nothing to do there. And decide: is it $\;\sin^4x\;$ or $\;\sin x^4\;$ ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)=-6\sin^4 x=-6(\sin x)^4$

By Chain Rule,

$f'(x)=4\cdot-6(\sin x)^3(\sin x)'=-24(\sin x)^3\cos x=-24\sin^3x\cos x$

Answer (score 1):

**Steps::** Note this is a candidate for the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule).

$$\text{Let } \space y = f(x) = -6\sin^4(x)$$
$$\text{Let } \space u=\sin(x) \Rightarrow y=-6u^4$$

To find $f'(x)$:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm dx}=\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm du}\cdot\frac{\mathrm du}{\mathrm dx}\tag{1}$$
$$\frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}=-6(4)u^3\cdot \cos(x)= -24\sin^3(x)\cos(x)$$

$(1)$ can also be expressed as $(f \circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$ Where $g(x)$ is the inner function $\sin(x)$ and $f(u)$ is the outer function $-6u^4$

Answer (score 1):

Whether $f(x) = -6\sin^4 x = -6(\sin x)^4$ or $f(x) = -6 \sin (x^4)$, the chain rule is the way to go.

If

$f(x) = -6(\sin x)^4, \tag{1}$

set

$u = \sin x \tag{2}$

so that (1) becomes

$f(u(x)) = -6(u(x))^4; \tag{3}$

now we apply the chain rule, which says that $df(u(x))/dx$ is given by

$\dfrac{df(u(x))}{dx} = \dfrac{df}{du}(u(x)) \dfrac{du}{dx}(x). \tag{4}$

We see that

$\dfrac{df(u(x))}{du}(u(x)) = -24(u(x))^3 = -24 (\sin x)^3 \tag{5}$

and

$\dfrac{du}{dx} = \cos x, \tag{6}$

whence, by (4),

$\dfrac{df(u(x))}{dx} = -24 (\sin x)^3 \cos x. \tag{7}$

On the other hand if

$f(x) = -6\sin(x^4), \tag{8}$

then we take

$u(x) = x^4 \tag{9}$

so that (8) yields

$f(u(x)) = -6 \sin u(x), \tag{10}$

from which we have

$\dfrac{df(u(x))}{du}(u(x)) = -6 \cos u(x) = -6 \cos x^4; \tag{11}$

also,

$\dfrac{du}{dx} = 4x^3; \tag{12}$

pulling (11) and (12) together with the aid of (4) gives the result

$\dfrac{df((x))}{dx} = -24x^3 \cos x^4. \tag{13}$

Either way, The Chain Rule rules!  Long Live The Chain Rule!

Hope this helps.  Cheers,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, $\sin^4x$ and $\sin x^4$ are completely different.

By convention, $\sin^4x = (\sin x)^4$, the fourth power of $\sin x$.

Also by convention, $\sin x^4 = \sin (x^4)$, the sine of the fourth power of $x$.

But here are derivatives for both $f(x) = -6 \sin^4 x$ and $g(x) = -6 \sin x^4$:

$$f'(x) = -6 \frac{d}{dx} \left(\sin^4 x\right) = -24 \sin^3x \frac{d}{dx} \sin x = -24 \sin^3x \cos x.$$

$$g'(x) = -6 \frac{d}{dx} \left(\sin x^4\right) = - 6 \cos x^4 \frac{d}{dx} x^4 = -24 x^3 \cos x^4.$$